# Is it possible to chain populate() method calls conditionally?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm creating a database service for my app but for some code. There is a lot of populate.
So is it possible to add something like:

```
if (populateFriends) {
  .populate('friends')
}
if (populatePosts) {
  .populate('posts')
}
```

And add the end it automatically add it to find().populate('friends').populate('posts');

Because now I got something like this:

```
  Action.find({ completed: false, userRole: ROLES.ADMIN }, selection)
    .populate({
      path: 'tender',
      select: 'number description shipper carriers type',
      populate: {
        path: 'shipper',
        select: 'company firstName lastName',
        populate: {
          path: 'company',
          select: 'companyName'
        }
      }
    })
    .sort({ creationDate: -1 })
    .populate('additionalData.documentId'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Build an array of things to populate. You can build this array dynamically, then pass it to Mongoose:

```
let toPopulate = [];

if (populateTenders) {
    toPopulate.push({
        path: 'tender',
        select: 'number description shipper carriers type',
        model: Tender
    });
}
if (populateShippers) {
    toPopulate.push({
        path: 'shipper',
        select: 'company firstName lastName',
        model : Shipper 
    })
}

myModel.find({})
    .populate(toPopulate) // Now you populate both Tenders and Shippers, conditionally
    .exec(...)
```